# Update from two tables but failed

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have two tables, `company_info` and `comp_orders`

I run following query:

```
$sql = "Update s1 SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
        Where s1.Comp_Name=s2.Comp_Name AND 
        s1.ID_No='$id' FROM comp_orders s1 , company_info s2";
```

But it is not working. THe error returned is

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM comp_orders s1 ,company_info s2' at line 1"

Comment: s1.ID_No='$id' comes from a diff php form to set particular ID_No details for updation

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin then go to your **localhost/phpmyadmin**
and then to SQL option (after structure in the header) and then try your sql query there with actual vales and see weather it is working or not. e.g. select * from abc where name="qwe";

Answer (score 1):

You should `JOIN` the two tables like so:

```
Update comp_orders s1
INNER JOIN  company_info s2 ON s1.Comp_Name=s2.Comp_Name 
SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
[Where ...] --optional perediate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE comp_orders s1
INNER JOIN company_info s2 on s1.Comp_Name=s2.Comp_Name
SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
WHERE s1.ID_No = '$id'
```

[simplified SQL fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f64a)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `FROM` inside `update`

the query should be

```
$sql = "Update s1 SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr Where s1.Comp_Name=s2.Comp_Name AND s1.ID_No='$id'";
```

Comment: And where are 's1' and 's2' being assigned the proper table names?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the update query wrong. I think the following should work:

```
$sql = "
    Update comp_orders s1, company_info s2 SET 
        s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
        Where s1.Comp_Name=s2.Comp_Name AND s1.ID_No='$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "Update s1 SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr Where s1.Comp_Name=s2.Comp_Name AND s1.ID_No='$id' FROM comp_orders.s1 , company_info.s2";
```

Try this instead, you were missing dots..

There are other errors aswell - look up [updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Please read http://w3fools.com/ before continuing to send people to w3schools; try the authoritative documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html instead.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE … FROM`? Which SQL dialect is this? I've never saw it before.

There is no `FROM` in an MySQL `UPDATE`-clause: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

What if you try the following:

```
UPDATE comp_orders s1, company_info s2
SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
WHERE s1.Comp_Name = s2.Comp_Name 
AND s1.ID_No='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
UPDATE comp_orders s1
INNER JOIN company_info s2 USING(`Comp_Name`)
SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
WHERE s1.ID_No = '$id'
```

or

```
UPDATE comp_orders s1 company_info s2 
SET s1.Comp_Addr = s2.Comp_Addr 
WHERE s1.ID_No='$id'
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)